# Confusion on adding event to ExtendedCalendarView

Tags: android, view, calendar

I am trying to follow https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView instructions for adding an event to the calendar. The calendar is showing up but I do not see any changes in the color of the dates.

In my onCreate method I have added

```
    calendar = (ExtendedCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarProvider.COLOR, Event.COLOR_BLUE);
    values.put(CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION, "Some Description");
    values.put(CalendarProvider.LOCATION, "Some location");
    values.put(CalendarProvider.EVENT, "Event name");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    cal.set(2015, 8, 1, 1, 1);
    int StartDayJulian = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
    values.put(CalendarProvider.START, cal.getTimeInMillis());
    values.put(CalendarProvider.START_DAY, StartDayJulian);

    cal.set(2015, 8, 1, 1, 1);
    int endDayJulian = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));

    values.put(CalendarProvider.END, cal.getTimeInMillis());
    values.put(CalendarProvider.END_DAY, endDayJulian);

    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Thanks for your help.